# Move site root directory on debian

Tags: apache, configuration, linux

I installed WordPress on Debian using [this article from the Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WordPress). My `wp.conf` looks like

```
Alias /wp/wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
Alias /wp /usr/share/wordpress
<Directory /usr/share/wordpress>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride Limit Options FileInfo
DirectoryIndex index.php
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content>
Options FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

since I couldn't get the virtual host config file to work. This makes the site visible under `mydomain.com/wp`. How can I make the site visible at `mydomain.com`? I tried changing the site URL, but that made the site unviewable and I had to manually change the URL values back in the database. Changing `Alias /wp` to `Alias /` results in 403s trying to access the root directory. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following some other toturial instead of one that lacks any explanations as to the "why" like this one. Linode and digitalocean should have good toturial on how to install wordpress, and although they might not be debian specific, the once regarding ubuntu should probably be compatible with debian.

To answer the question, you need to remove the `/wp` part of the alias and get something like

```
Alias /wp-content /var/lib/wordpress/wp-content
Alias / /usr/share/wordpress
```

And again, I would not setup wordpress like that in two different directories without a reason.